# Testing if kdb is accepting connections from bash

Tags: bash, kdb

This is my kbd script. 
It does rely on copious environment files. I have scripts that fail on connecting to the KDB database because it is too busy to accept connections. 
I want to test the connection to kdb before running a script. I just want to know if kdb is accepting connections and have it equal to a bash exit value. 0 or 1
This is my KDB script:

```
system "l ",(getenv`CASPER),"/CASPER/q/CASPER_lib.q";
system "l ",(getenv`CASPER),"/CASPER/q/report_lib.q";
system "l ",(getenv`CASPER),"/reporting/q/reporting_utils.q";
\c 50 2000
\P 0

\p 0W
port:system"p"
3 (string port),"\n"
hclose 3

params:.Q.def [(`tradedate`CASPERhost)!(.z.d;`)] .Q.opt .z.x;
tradedate:params`tradedate;
CASPERhost:string params`CASPERhost;

h:.U.connect[`kdb;CASPERhost;"";()];
h1:.U.connect[`kdb;getenv`QUERY_GATEWAY;"";()];    


hclose h;
hclose h1;
```

All i want to do is test the connection to kdb - from a bash script. Open and close, just to see if I can connect to the database
Howeer when I run the bash, it goes to a q prompt. whih i have to manually close out with a \ (two slashes). How can i test that the kdb database is accepting connections from a bash script.

This is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
q kdb_filehandle.q
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the exit command from with q to terminate with an exit code;

```
q)exit 1
$ echo $?
1

q) exit 0
$ echo $?
0
```

With this in mind you can error trap your connections and have them exit with an 1 if they fail/ For example if you wanted to trap your hopen you would use

```
.[.U.connect;(`kdb;CASPERhost;"";());exit 1]
```

Here . is the trap operator, .U.connect is your function, your arguments are passed in as a list (), and the third parameter is the statement to execute on error, in this case exit 1.

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/errors/#trap

You can also execute q scripts as a shebang to aviod having to wrap your script in bash. Just start your script with;

```
#!/usr/bin/env q
```

http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/faq/#can-i-execute-q-as-a-shebang-script